# Differences Between Desktop / Mobile @ VW=360

Tags: css, wordpress, responsive-design

I've posted this question on the support site for my Wordpress theme but haven't had any luck over there yet.
When I resize my browser window to 360px (360 because thats what my viewport width is on my Samsung Galaxy S6) I see something totally different than when I try to access my site on my phone.

My site is www.andrewpennell.com
What I've designed and am supposed to see is in the picture below. 
[Correct Design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WTOHB.png)

But that's now what I see on mobile.
When I load my page on my mobile device I see several issues:
a) The background image doesn't seem to scale down - this may just be a simple media query I need to add.
b) My Logo, Name, and Subtitle are no where in sight (although I've seen them randomly load up under the menu bar where I can barely see a sliver of them. 
c) At the bottom, social buttons and sharing go behind the footer

My primary concern at the time is problem B.

Any helpful comments are welcome. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Wow. Rude. Next time just stay at home.

Comment: Also, there is a ton of custom CSS in there specifically written to override things. Next time try to write something helpful instead of taking shots at people.

Answer (score 0):

- Check the source code for the page (right click => view source)
- Do a browser find (ctrl-f) for `viewport`

If you don't see a meta tag something like this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
```

then you're going to experience issues with small high res screens like the one on an S6.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look. I looked last night to make sure this was there. Scale is set at 1.